# Select the correct Lists by using if statement c#

Tags: c#, .net

```
if (gardenvlist.Count() == days)
{

}

if (oceanvlist.Count() == days)
{

}

if (cityvlist.Count() == days)
{

}
```

I'm trying to do, if the statements `if (gardenvlist.Count() == days)`, etc are true select the list for display. If the statement is false do not select the list. I wanted to select the ones that are true and combine them. I tried AddRange but its a list so I cant do that. Please help.

Comment: What range are you trying to add to what? What does "select the list for display" mean?

Comment: If they are lists why are you using the method `Count()` and not the property `.Count`?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "select" and "combine them"?

Comment: Is it safe to assume these lists are all of the same type?

Comment: @supsupdb huh? You replied "yeah" to a request for a further explanation of your question, same thing to Ed.

Comment: @RufusL The items in the list have the same type.

Comment: @gilliduck Sorry about it. I misunderstand your question. What I mean is, I will check if the objects in the list are matched with the days (which is a range between two dates. If they are the same then it should select the list for further process, which will be combining to other lists that are true and then display them.

Comment: Didn't you just post this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by, *"I tried AddRange but its a list so I cant do that."* You can absolutely use `AddRange` on lists, as long as they're of the same type.

Here's an example that is using a list of strings, but it should work for your type as long as all your lists are of the same type (hint: post a small code sample that people can use to test with next time, including a small class definition if needed).

```
private static void Main()
{
    var gardenvlist = new List<string> {"Garden One", "Garden Two"};
    var oceanvlist = new List<string> {"Ocean One", "Ocean Two", "Ocean Three"};
    var cityvlist = new List<string> {"City One", "City Two"};

    int days = 2;

    var allValidItems = new List<string>();

    if (gardenvlist.Count == days)
    {
        allValidItems.AddRange(gardenvlist);
    }

    if (oceanvlist.Count == days)
    {
        allValidItems.AddRange(oceanvlist);
    }

    if (cityvlist.Count == days)
    {
        allValidItems.AddRange(cityvlist);
    }

    foreach (var validItem in allValidItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(validItem);
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Concat()` function to combine two lists and return a new list, without modifying the used ones.

```
var newList = list1.Concat(list2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a new list at the start then use add range to put the lists your counting into that new list.
Finally return the list you created